# PHP jquery load data remote file not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I need to load data into bootstrap modal box.

step1: mypage.php (require `config.php` and all `php class`)

```
require $abspath . '/config.php';

require ABSPATH . '/functions.php';

require ABSPATH . '/class/csrf.php';

require ABSPATH . '/class/mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

<div>.......ALL HTML</div>

$(function() {

    $('.push').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../controller/remotefile.php', // in here you should put your query 
            data: 'cmid=' + id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
            // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
            success: function(r) {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
                $('#cm').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    }) // put your modal id 
                $('.something').show().html(r);
            }
        });


    });

});
```

step2: remotefile.php  (require `config.php` and all `php class` **again**)

```
require $abspath . '/config.php';

require ABSPATH . '/functions.php';

require ABSPATH . '/class/csrf.php';

require ABSPATH . '/class/mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['cmid'])){
$DB =  mysqli::f("SELECT * FROM " . BOOKS . " WHERE id = ?",filter_var($_POST['cmid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
print_r($DB);
}
```

for this case I require `config.php` and all `php class` into each page (remote page and root page).

this *worked* for me but when I remove `config.php` and all `php class` from remote file I see php error for db config and more php error.

I think this is not good way for insert `config.php` and all `php class` to both pages. can I remove  `config.php` and all `php class` from `remotefile.php` and my script worked true? any way ? any idea?

Comment: You've missed quotes when including `functions.php`

Comment: one missing quote can do a lot of difference

Comment: @Tushar: I edit this, But this Is not my problem !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No, you cannot remove the `config.php` and php class files from your `remogefile.php` file".

What is in your `config.php` file? My guess is that you are setting up your database there, like telling PHP what your DB host, username, password, etc are. So if you don't include that file, they are all not set and you get the DB error (think, where `mysqli::f` should execute the query?).

You question also makes me think that you expect the `config.php` file to be already included in the `mypage.php` file and there's no need to require it again.

If so consider how many requests happen when the user visits your `mypage.php`.

1. Initially, the first request for the `mypage.php` is created, the file executes and includes all the files you require, including `config.php`. When it completes execution, the request is finished and the page is rendered in the browser.
2. The JS-code in that rendered page initialises a fresh new request where your `remotefile.php` is called. This new request has nothing to do, in terms of the executed PHP code, with the previous one. So no `config.php` is yet required, the DB is not configured.

Therefor you need to require those files (`config.php` and all the class files) in each, well, page that you make requests to. Well, I don't see that you use any of the included classes in the `remotefile.php` file, so acutal

I could think of the following things to make php files clean and concise:

- Consider the [autoloading PHP feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to eliminate the need for separate `require` lines for each class you use in your code.
- I could also recommend to implement the "[Single Entry Point](http://www.janoszen.com/2013/01/08/writing-modern-day-php-applications/)" technique used by all the MVC framework these days.